# Jenkins Groovy: how to increment 2 or 3 digit numbers?

Tags: groovy, increment, jenkins-groovy

I have a strange problem with incrementation in Groovy using `++`.

Look, when I have one digit, it all works:

```
def lastNumber = "3"
def incrementedLastNumber = ++lastNumber
```

**​Result: 4**

What is interesting is works for 2 decimals as well, however not with the next one, as a result, it should be 10, 20, 30, and so on, look:

```
def lastNumber = "18"
def incrementedLastNumber = ++lastNumber
```

**​Result: 19**

```
def lastNumber = "19"
def incrementedLastNumber = ++lastNumber
```

**​Result: 1:**

Why it can't increment when there is 19 or 29, or 39? There is always `1:` or `2:` or `3:` as a result. The same issue is for 3 decimal numbers 101 works, but 119 doesn't work and the result is `11:`.

How should I do this to make sure that every number will be properly incremented?

Comment: Use integer values instead of String values. Strings are for displaying *text*.

Comment: When I changed def to int it started to work! I didn't think this can be a reason! Thank you!

Comment: Groovy tries to be clever with single digit integers, and adds one to the ASCII value (which happens to be the next number)...  Once you get to 2 digits, all bets are off

Comment: you can not hope, that strings will be incremented as integers